# Dual citizenship document verification/validation

Tags: dual-citizenship

I was born in country C1, moved abroad to study for master and work on country C2. Then got citizenship from country C3.

While on C2, I worked on company K1 using passport from country A1. Now I'm about to change job to company K2 and I would like to use my brand new passport from country C3, meaning the visa stamp will go on C3 passport and I guess C1 passport will receive stamp to cancel the visa. I'm still living on country C2.

All my documents, i.e. master degree certificate, refer to C1 passport. To receive the work visa I have to present many documents, i.e. master degree certificate. But these documents refer to the other passport and I have a feeling I should tie this things together.

Perhaps I should ask 1) Who is the authority who will tie these things together? Or is there a document that ties these things?

Comment: Where was the master degree certificate issued that contains the citizenship and/or passport information?

Comment: Are you a dual citizen or did you need to give up C1 when you got C3 ?

Comment: Master degree was issued on C2.

Comment: I have dual citizenship, I don't need to give up any. I just want to effectivelly use the new citizenship.

Comment: What is country A1?  Is it the same as country C1?  This is confusing.  Just name the countries.